# MQL help required, how to generate key

Tags: mql4

I am struggling with one code line.  It is a Key generation Line for a Expert Adviser.   Can someone help me figure out how I can generate key by using this line:

```
int key=3*(StringToInteger(StringSubstr(IntegerToString(AccountNumber()), 0, 3)))+333333;
```

Comment: what do you want? to understand what all that mean? To know what is the output if you know the account number? or you decompiled and want to find the right code into ea?

Answer (score 0):

And what is the problem?

`int accountNumber = AccountNumber();
 string accountNumberString = IntegerToString(accountNumber);
 string accountNumberStringFirst3Digits=
StringSubstr(accountNumberString,0,3);
 int accountNumberFirstThreeDigits = StringToInteger(accountNumberStringFirst3Digits);
 int accountNumberFirstThreeDigitsMultiplied = 3 * accountNumberFirstThreeDigits;
 int key = accountNumberFirstThreeDigitsMultiplied + 333333;`

Answer (score 0):

### Can someone help me figure out how to generate key by this line?

Welcome, certainly, let's look on that :

```
int key = 3*(StringToInteger(StringSubstr(IntegerToString(AccountNumber()), 0, 3)))+333333;
```

Your code actually means this:

```
//   +------------------------------------------------------------------------------- type declaration
//   |   +--------------------------------------------------------------------------- variable name definition
//   |   | +------------------------------------------------------------------------- assignment operator
//   |   | | +----------------------------------------------------------------------- compile-time integer constant
//   |   | | | +--------------------------------------------------------------------- multiply operator
//   |   | | | |                  +-------------------------------------------------- MT4 system function: StringToInteger( aString )
//   |   | | | |                  |             +------------------------------------ MT4 system function: StringSubstr(    aString, aPosToStartSubstrFrom, aSubstrLength )
//   |   | | | |                  |             |                +------------------- MT4 system function: IntegerToString( aIntNum )                    |              |
//   |   | | | |                  |             |                |              +---- MT4 system function: AccountNumber()                               |              |
//   |   | | | |                  |             |                |              |                                                                        |              |
//   |   | | | |                  |             |                |              |     +------------------------------------------------------------------+              |
//   |   | | | |                  |             |                |              |     |  +------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
//   |   | | | |                  |             |                |              |     |  |
   int key = 3 * ( StringToInteger( StringSubstr( IntegerToString( AccountNumber() ), 0, 3 ) ) )
           + 333333;
//         |      ||
//         +------||----------------------------------------------------------------- add operator
//                +|----------------------------------------------------------------- compile-time integer constant
//                 +----------------------------------------------------------------- literal MQL4-language syntax-terminator
```

The code above both defines and generates a fair integer value, so wherever your Expert Advisor code refers to a value of **`key`**, this calculated value will be used ( see also the documentation about the *New*-MQL4 scope-of-validity, inside which this variable remains visible ).